# Source code in multiple targeting framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, multitargeting

I have a solution which contains 3 projects (**NetCoreWeb**, **NetFrameworkWeb**, **SharedLibrary**)

- **NetCoreWeb**: *.Net Core 2.2*
- **NetFrameworkWeb**: *Net Framework 4.5.2*
- **SharedLibrary**: *NetCoreApp 2.2* & *Net Framework 4.5.2*

[image]

This is the source code in **MessageService.cs** which is in **SharedLibrary** project:

```
public class MessageService
    {
        public string GetMessage()
        {
#if NETFRAMEWORK
            return "Net Framework";
#elif NETSTANDARD
            return "Net Standard";
#else
            return "Not supported";
#endif
        }
    }
```

Every time, only the source code in **#elif NETSTANDARD** is active and available for debugging, even I set **NetFrameworkWeb** as the active project:

[image]

How can I make the source code in **#if NETFRAMEWORK** block to be active when I set **NetFrameworkWeb** as an active project, and set the rest to be active when **#elif NETSTANDARD** is set as active ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The `#if`* statements are compile-time definitions. Since your library targets .NET Standard only (as far as i can tell from the screenshot and described behaviour), the source code is compiled with the `NETSTANDARD` constant.

This resulting binary is then used from your .NET Core and .NET Framework projects so the string value does not change because they are used from a different project.

If you absolutely need to implement different behaviours for different runtimes, you will need to set up your library as multi-targeting project instead of a .NET Standard project by changing the library's csproj file from

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;net452</TargetFrameworks>
```

(note the additional `s` in `TargetFrameworks`)